# Capture multiple matches from the same Perl regex?

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file containing text:

```
hello mayank1 kumar mayank21
yadav Kevin has at most 
K
K minutes to perform this operations. He decides mayank3 that the string is super mayank4
if it is the lexicographically 
smallest among all possible strings mayank15
that he can get. Your task is to help Kevin and 
find this mayank2 lexicographically mayank8 smallest string mayank9
```

How can i find all `mayank<number>` ?

I tried:

```
use strict;

open( FH, "testfile.txt" ) or die "Can't open file for reading.";
while ( my $line = <FH> ) {
    chomp($line);
    while ( $line =~ /(mayank.*?)/g ) {
        print "$1\n";
    }
}
```

which is giving:

```
mayank
mayank
mayank
mayank
mayank
mayank
mayank
mayank
```

When using:

```
while ($line =~ /(mayank.?)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

I get

```
mayank1
mayank2
mayank3
mayank4
mayank1
mayank2
mayank8
mayank9
```

Please suggest.

Comment: What do you mean by find all "mayank" ? What output do you expect your program to produce?

Comment: Sorry for incomplete, i am loking for o/p as:
mayank1\n
mayank21\n
mayank3\n
mayank4\n
mayank15\n
mayank2\n
mayank8\n
mayank9\n

Comment: I just edited the post (improved formatting) and noticed that the desired result wasn't surrounded by backticks, so we couldn't see the `<number>` part in `mayank<number>`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to capture `mayank` followed by a number, you can use the following regex :

```
while ($line =~ /(mayank\d*)/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

If the number is mandatory, change it to `/(mayank\d+)/`.

**Short explanation** :  `\d` matches a single digit, so `\d*` matches as many digits as possible (or zero if there is none), and `\d+` matches as many digit as possible (but at least one).

**Why your solutions didn't work** :

`/(mayank.*?)/` uses a non-greedy quantifier (`*?`), which try to match at little characters as possible, so nothing.
`/(mayank.?)/` will capture whatever character comes after `mayank` (even a space), if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

You want to capture **mayank#id** where **id** is a number or nothing:

```
$line =~ /(mayank)(\d+)?/
```

- **$1** : will hold mayank
- **$2** : will hold the **id** or will be empty (undef)

You may find more information about regular expression with Perl reading the manual:

```
man perlre
```

Comment: Almost ;-) Consider a line containing `mayank` (without a number). `$line =~ /(mayank)(\d+)?/g` will catch `$1` as `mayank` and `$2` as `undef`. On the other hand `$line =~ /(mayank)(\d*)/g` will catch `$1` as `mayank` and `$2` as `''` (the empty string). The difference comes up when you `print "$1 - $2\n";`: the 1st solution complains about `$2` being undefined while the 2nd just prints an empty string. "empty" and "undef" are two different things in Perl (not only in Perl).

Comment: Generally I use a modified statement: print " $1 - $2\n" if $1 and $2; to avoid warnings. I Agree that using the (\d*) would force an empty match, therefore setting $2 to be "" (empty string).