# Perl - Returning Multiple "Same" Matches from one string

Tags: regex, perl

I have string of the form:

```
column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/QCOM\u0027\u003EQUALCOMM Incorporated\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.99%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/ADI\u0027\u003EAnalog Devices, Inc.\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.88%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/NXPI\u0027\u003ENXP Semiconductors NV\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.83%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/NOK\u0027\u003ENokia Oyj Sponsored ADR\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.53%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/ERIC\u0027\u003ETelefonaktiebolaget
```

that is - it has multiple instances of "`stock\\\/`" in that single line. For example, it has "`stock\\\/QCOM\u0027\`", then "`stock\\\/ADI\u0027\`", then "`stock\\\/NXPI\u0027\`" and so on

What I need is to extract every single 3/4 letter code that follows the "`stock\\\/`" pattern. 
In the above case, I need to extract the values of "`QCOM, ADI, NXPI,`" and so on as the output

I consulted the thread [Capture multiple matches from the same Perl regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39435914/capture-multiple-matches-from-the-same-perl-regex) and tried the following, but despite using "g" it is returning only the first match. I need the whole list.

```
    if ($_ =~ /stock\\\\\\\/(.*?)\\u0027/g)
    {
        print "-$1-";
    }
```

Any idea how to achieve that, please?
Thanks

Comment: Replace `if` with `while` or call search in list context: `@matches = ($_ =~ /stock\\\\\\\/(.*?)\\u0027/g)`. You can also omit `$_` as it is default.

Comment: Why are you using a regex to extract information from JSON-encoded HTML? Properly parse the JSON, then properly parse the HTML, then extract the information from the attributes.

Comment: @ikegami, this is a sample. My requirement may extend beyond JSON and HTML to general texts. That's why I am looking for "regex" solution.

Comment: @Alex, while works. Thanks a ton! How do I mark your comment as an answer?

Comment: You can't mark the comment as an answer. You can maybe upvote on it.

Comment: @Alex - yup, that I know and have upvoted. And since that comment has solved the stated problem, it deserves to get the answer tag. How about you putting it as an answer and I marking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `if` with `while` or call search in list context:

```
@matches = ($_ =~ /stock\\\\\\\/(.*?)\\u0027/g)
```

You can also omit $_ as it is default, so either

```
while (/stock\\\\\\\/(.*?)\\u0027/g)
{
    print "-$1-";
}
```

or

```
@matches = /stock\\\\\\\/(.*?)\\u0027/g;
```

Answer (score -1):

Please see if next code snippet any use to you

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my %company;
my $data = <DATA>;

%company = $data =~ m!stock.*?/(.*?)\\.*?u003E(.*?)\\u003C!g;

say "Symbol\tDescription";
say '-' x 35;

while( my($s,$d) = each %company ) {
    say "$s\t$d";
}

__DATA__
column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/QCOM\u0027\u003EQUALCOMM Incorporated\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.99%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/ADI\u0027\u003EAnalog Devices, Inc.\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.88%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/NXPI\u0027\u003ENXP Semiconductors NV\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.83%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/NOK\u0027\u003ENokia Oyj Sponsored ADR\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.53%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/ERIC\u0027\u003ETelefonaktiebolaget
```

Output

```
Symbol  Description
-----------------------------------
NXPI    NXP Semiconductors NV
QCOM    QUALCOMM Incorporated
NOK     Nokia Oyj Sponsored ADR
ADI     Analog Devices, Inc.
```

Answer (score -1):

Extracted symbols of companies can be printed out with following code

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

my $data = <DATA>;

my @data = $data =~ m!stock.*?/(.*?)\\!g;

say for @data;

__DATA__
column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/QCOM\u0027\u003EQUALCOMM Incorporated\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.99%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/ADI\u0027\u003EAnalog Devices, Inc.\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.88%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/NXPI\u0027\u003ENXP Semiconductors NV\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.83%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/NOK\u0027\u003ENokia Oyj Sponsored ADR\u003C\\\/a\u003E\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column2\\\u0022\u003E4.53%\u003C\\\/td\u003E\\n        \u003C\\\/tr\u003E\\n        \u003Ctr\u003E\\n          \u003Ctd class=\\\u0022view_all_column1\\\u0022\u003E\u003Ca href=\u0027\\\/stock\\\/ERIC\u0027\u003ETelefonaktiebolaget
```

Output

```
QCOM
ADI
NXPI
NOK
ERIC
```